# scrapy timeout not controlling twisted timeout

Tags: scrapy

I keep getting this when I run my scrapy spider `raise TimeoutError("Getting %s took longer than %s seconds." % (url, timeout))
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.exampletest.com/test took longer than 190 seconds..`

I have set the following settings but didn't help

```
'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':False,
'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':20,
'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
```

How can I control if the website doesn't respond in under 30 sec to just pass or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

`190` is a weird default, so I’ll go ahead and assume that you are using [scrapy-crawlera](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-crawlera).

If that is the case, know that `scrapy-crawlera` ignores `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` because Crawlera requires higher timeout values, as requests through [Crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera) can take much longer.

If you want to decrease the timeout value nonetheless, change [`CRAWLERA_DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT`](https://scrapy-crawlera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#crawlera-download-timeout) instead.

Comment: your assumption is correct, I do use crawlera. what do you think is a good time out for Google,Amazon to keep the results correct